# Computer algebra programs for dummies

Tags: computational-number-theory, computation, elimination-theory

In the way of my investigations I have encounter the following computational problem: I have a system of 5 algebraic equations and I want to eliminate 4 of them. I also need to do a functional inversion at the end.

I am using Maple (joing with gfun and Gröbner basis) but it seems that the program is not digesting well the functions, and it is not able to proceed (it makes some computations, but unfortunately it is not working).

My question is the following: which are the usual programs and packages used to deal with algebraic functions and elimination theory (also Gröbner basis). I know Maple, but of course any other suggestion will be greatly welcome.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/q/181350/11260

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Implementations